# Hive - how to perform operation on state change

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two columns in my hive table. col2 contains values 'Y' and 'N'. In hive I would like to loop through the table and if every time there is a state change(from N to Y or from Y to N), I would like to insert a new row in another table. How do I do that using hiveql? Thanks guys!

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us your code!

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into my_target

select  ...

from   (select  col2
               ,lag (col2) over (order by ...)  as prev_col2

        from    my_source
        ) t

where   t.col2 <>  prev_col2
;
```

#### Demo

```
with my_source as (select posexplode(split('YYNYNNNYYY','\\B')) as (col1,col2))
select  * from my_source;
```

---

```
+----------------+----------------+
| my_source.col1 | my_source.col2 |
+----------------+----------------+
| 0              | Y              |
+----------------+----------------+
| 1              | Y              |
+----------------+----------------+
| 2              | N              |
+----------------+----------------+
| 3              | Y              |
+----------------+----------------+
| 4              | N              |
+----------------+----------------+
| 5              | N              |
+----------------+----------------+
| 6              | N              |
+----------------+----------------+
| 7              | Y              |
+----------------+----------------+
| 8              | Y              |
+----------------+----------------+
| 9              | Y              |
+----------------+----------------+
```

---

```
with my_source as (select posexplode(split('YYNYNNNYYY','\\B')) as (col1,col2))

select  *

from   (select  col1
               ,col2
               ,lag (col2) over (order by col1)  as prev_col2

        from    my_source
        ) t

where   t.col2 <>  prev_col2
;
```

---

```
+--------+--------+-------------+
| t.col1 | t.col2 | t.prev_col2 |
+--------+--------+-------------+
| 2      | N      | Y           |
+--------+--------+-------------+
| 3      | Y      | N           |
+--------+--------+-------------+
| 4      | N      | Y           |
+--------+--------+-------------+
| 7      | Y      | N           |
+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: select statement below of insert statement should be diff table name not the my_source.

Comment: @DineshSingh, actually no, the WITH clause is here only for the generation of the data sample for demo and is not part of the real solution.